# Weighted Search algoritim based on tag occurrences in java

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, search, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build an algorithm to return a list of images with the highest relevance to a user.

So a user will have a List of Tags and the occurrences of each.

So the tags associated with the user will look as follows(map):

```
Photography ->4
trees       ->3
nature      ->3
snow        ->2
lake        ->2
sky         ->2
```

In my database, I have a list of images with tags.
An example would be:

```
**Image1**: photography, animals, nature, snow
**Image2**: photography, trees, lake, sky
**Image3**: sky, animals, dark, moon
```

So using a map of tags, I want to search the database for images with the highest similarity and giving weight to those with more occurrences.

So an image with the tags: **photography, trees, nature** present would be giving a higher weight than an image with the tags: **nature, sky, moon**

I tried taking the top occurrences, eg. **photography** and search all these images, then from this result List, search the next word from the map, in this case, **trees** and then interchange **trees** for **nature** as it has the same occurrences, thus returning a list of ranked images.

I am doing in java and using MySQL to store the userTags & occurrences and the images & tags.

I feel there is a better way to return a ranked list based on this information.

The way I am doing it is by giving each image a score based on their tags and the corresponding value.

So     image 1 would be a score of photography, animals, nature, snow (4+0+3+2) = 8 

    And image 2 photography, trees, lake, sky(4+3+2+2) = 11

    And image 3 sky, animals, dark, moon (2+0+0+0) = 2

So the ranked list return would be Image 2, Image 1, Image 3 based on this score

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably exactly why we have nosql databases, but it can of course by done in sql.
Create an entity for each tag (NB I started with the example set, but gave up trying to represent it all):

```
 create table tagged(WHO varchar2(20),tag VARCHAR2(20),what varchar2(20));
/* WHAT I tagged */
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','PHOTOGRAPHY','IMAGEX');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','PHOTOGRAPHY','IMAGEY');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','PHOTOGRAPHY','IMAGEZ');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','PHOTOGRAPHY','IMAGEA');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','TREES','IMAGEB');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','TREES','IMAGEC');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','TREES','IMAGED');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','NATURE','IMAGEE');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','NATURE','IMAGEF');
INSERT INTO TAGGED VALUES('USER','NATURE','IMAGEG');
/* a subset of interest */
insert into tagged VALUES('JOE','PHOTOGRAPHY','IMAGE1');
insert into tagged VALUES('FRED','ANIMALS','IMAGE1');
insert into tagged VALUES('WILMA','TREES','IMAGE1');
insert into tagged VALUES('WILMA','NATURE','IMAGE1');
```

now create a view summarising these (this could be done in sql, but I find views can aid comprehension at the early stage).

```
create view popularity as select tag,what,count(*) popularity from tagged group by tag,what;
```

and now we can select the most popular things based on the above algorithm* like so:

```
select  p.what,sum(p.popularity) 
from popularity p,tagged u
where u.who='USER'
and u.tag=p.tag
group by p.what 
order by 2 desc;
IMAGE1  10
IMAGEA  4
IMAGEX  4
IMAGEZ  4
IMAGEY  4
IMAGEF  3
IMAGED  3
IMAGEE  3
IMAGEC  3
IMAGEB  3
IMAGEG  3
```

- this implementation further weights the users tags by how often they
  use them - not an unreasonable thing

** it also counts images I've already tagged - I will leave it as an exercise for the user to exclude these

Answer (score 0):

if you do a join with user and tags and image you can order the result by the value of tag on the user side.

```
user   photography   4          **image1***
user   photography   4          **image2***
user   trees               3    ** Image2 ** 
user   nature             3     **image1***
```

Note

> stop asking question like this because you will be blocked like me from asking question for 6 month you should ask coding question not conception

Comment: try to find the query that do this if you don't put what you have did and may be we can help you

Comment: Thank for the response, I have updated the question to include my current method.

Comment: can you put the table struture and the query that you tried